# Ошибка подключения к базе данных Access

Tags: python, access, база-данных, sql

Я написал программу, которая с помощью pyodbc подключается к Access

```
import pyodbc
#import kinterbasdb
import firebirdsql
import os, sys
import json,sqlite3,sql
sys.version_info
s1='''
create table CLIENTS
    (
       ID    INTEGER NOT NULL,
       COMPANY   VARCHAR(50),
       "LAST NAME"   VARCHAR(50),
       "FIRST NAME"   VARCHAR(50),
       "E-MAIL ADDRESS"   VARCHAR(50),
       "JOB TITLE"   VARCHAR(50),
       "BUSINESS PHONE"   VARCHAR(25),
       "HOME PHONE"   VARCHAR(25),
       "MOBILE PHONE"   VARCHAR(25),
       "FAX NUMBER"   VARCHAR(25),
       ADDRESS   BLOB SUB_TYPE 1,
       CITY   VARCHAR(50),
       "STATE/PROVINCE"   VARCHAR(50),
       "ZIP/POSTAL CODE"   VARCHAR(15),
       "COUNTRY/REGION"   VARCHAR(50),
       "WEB-SITE"   VARCHAR(25),
       NOTES   BLOB SUB_TYPE 1,
       INCLUDING   BLOB,
       CONSTRAINT PK_CLIENTS_ID PRIMARY KEY(ID)
    );
'''
s2='''create ascending index IDX_CLIENTS_CITY on CLIENTS (CITY);'''
#os.remove('D:/ThirdTask/test1.fdb')
conn=firebirdsql.create_database(host='localhost', database='/test1.fdb', user='sysdba', password='masterkey')
#con=firebirdsql.connect(host='localhost',database='D:/ThirdTask/test1.fdb', user='sysdba', password='masterkey')
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute(s1)
#cur.execute(s2)
conn.commit()
conAcc = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)};DBQ=Northwind.accdb')
conn.close()
```

В результате выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ThirdTask\connecttwo.py", line 39, in <module>
    conAcc = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)};DBQ=Northwind.accdb')
Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][\xc4\xe8\xf1\xef\xe5\xf2\xf7\xe5\xf0 \xe4\xf0\xe0\xe9\xe2\xe5\xf0\xee\xe2 ODBC] \xc8\xf1\xf2\xee\xf7\xed\xe8\xea \xe4\xe0\xed\xed\xfb\xf5 \xed\xe5 \xed\xe0\xe9\xe4\xe5\xed \xe8 \xed\xe5 \xf3\xea\xe0\xe7\xe0\xed \xe4\xf0\xe0\xe9\xe2\xe5\xf0, \xe8\xf1\xef\xee\xeb\xfc\xe7\xf3\xe5\xec\xfb\xe9 \xef\xee \xf3\xec\xee\xeb\xf7\xe0\xed\xe8\xfe (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Comment: Может читабильная ошибка прояснит ситуацию
[IM002] [Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] Источник данных не найден и не указан драйвер, используемый по умолчанию (0) (SQLDriverConnect)

Comment: @moden , извините за непонятливость, а поподробнее объяснить можете.

Comment: Я сам понятия не имею. Просто перевел текст ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Надо было использовать вместо

```
conAcc = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)};DBQ=Northwind.accdb')
```

следующую строку подключения

```
conAcc = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=Northwind.accdb')
```